# Zend db insertion exception

Tags: php, zend-db

Please some body help me verified many times but i couldn't find where i did a mistake

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'Index_6'

This is my code:

```
$first_name = $_POST ['firstName'];
$middle_name = $_POST ['middleName'];
$last_name = $_POST ['lastName'];
$office_ph_no = $_POST ['officePhoneNumber'];
$cell_ph_no = $_POST ['cellPhoneNumber'];
$email = $_POST ['emailId'];
$supervisor_name = $_POST ['supervisorName'];
$supervisor_email = $_POST ['supervisorEmail'];
$supervisor_ph = $_POST ['supervisorPhone'];
$pass = $_POST ['password'];

$sql = $db->query ( "INSERT INTO user( user_id, title, first_name, last_name, user_identity_id, email_id, password, office_phone_number, public_id, session_id, address_id, created_by, last_modified_by, created_on, last_modified_on, is_activated, is_deprecated, middle_name, cell_phone_number, superviser_name, superviser_email, superviser_phone_number) 

VALUES ( :p_user_id, :p_title, :p_first_name, :p_last_name, :p_user_identity_id, :p_email_id, :p_password, :p_office_phone_number, :p_public_id, :p_session_id, :p_address_id, :p_created_by, :p_last_modified_by, :p_created_on, :p_last_modified_on, :p_is_activated, :p_is_deprecated, :p_middle_name, :p_cell_phone_number, :p_superviser_name, :p_superviser_email, :p_superviser_phone )",

   array (
'p_user_id' => '',
'p_title' => NULL,
'p_first_name' => $first_name,
'p_last_name' => $last_name,
'p_user_identity_id' => 'id',
'p_email_id' => $email,
'p_password' => $pass,
'p_office_phone_number' => $office_ph_no,
'p_public_id' => NULL,
'p_session_id' => NULL,
'p_address_id' => NULL,
'p_created_by' => NULL,
'p_last_modified_by' => NULL,
'p_created_on' => '',
'p_last_modified_on' => '',
'p_is_activated' => '0',
'p_is_deprecated' => '0',
'p_middle_name' => $middle_name,
'p_cell_phone_number' => $cell_ph_no,
'p_superviser_name' => $supervisor_name,
'p_superviser_email' => $supervisor_email,
'p_superviser_phone' => $supervisor_ph 
)
```

Comment: Which column has the constraint? Is it some of columns that you try to put NULL value, or column that you try to populate with value from $_POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In array the name 'p_ is_deprecated' has a blank space.

Comment: thanks for identifying after changing that i'm getting Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'Index_6' this error

Comment: In your db this primary key (Index_6) is already in use for another supervisor (I supose is supervisor) verify it.